# saving issues with multiple collections in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two schemas set up as:

```
 var mongoSchema =   mongoose.Schema;
// create schema
var UserSchema = new mongoSchema({
  name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },
  password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    LockID: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
      firstname: {
      type: String,
    },
      updated: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
      }
});

var LockLogSchema = new mongoSchema({
  lockTime: {
    type: String,
  },
  updated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
   },
    name: {
    type: String,
    required : true
  },  
    location:{
    type: String
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Logs',LockLogSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('userLogin',UserSchema);
```

However when I try and save to 'Logs' the request fails, but I can save to 'userLogin' fine.

My saving method is:

```
router.post('/unLock', function(req, res) {
    var now = moment().toDate();
    var db = new mongoOp({
                    name: req.body.name,
                    lockTime: now
                });
                // save the user
                console.log('create new user: ' + db);
                db.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).json({
                            success: false,
                        });
                      }
                        else
                        {
                          return res.status(500).json({
                              success: true,
                          });
                       }
                });
}
```

Which is invoked via a HTTP POST.

I think the issue is with exporting the two models to `module.exports`. But if I don't, how do I use router to POST the method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work this out myself.

I was using module.exports incorrectly and because of this was overwriting the exports with the second declaration.

This is how it should be set up:

```
var Logs = mongoose.model('Logs', LockLogSchema);
var userLogin = mongoose.model('userLogin', UserSchema);

module.exports = {
    Logs: Logs,
    userLogin: userLogin
};
```

Then the Schemas can be accessed like so:

```
    var mongoOp = require("../model/mongo");
    mongoOp.userLogin.findOne({});    //to find something 
    var db = new mongoOp.userLogin({});   //for saving
```